# Deriving potential inside a conductive, neutral shell containing a charge

Tags: electric-fields

The shell has radii $a$ and $b$ ($a<b$), and it has a point charge $q$ in the center. The field and potential in every possible region are:

[image: Screenshot from the slide]
I can't see how my professor derived the potential for the region $0<r<a$ (even though I can see why it makes sense). I've tried looking for the same result somewhere but I can't find any explanations. Useful links or any possible explanation are welcome.

Comment: Do you understand how they derived the electric field?

Comment: Actually it must be a conducting shell for the field to be $0$ inside.

Comment: Yes, I did understand how they derived $\vec{E}$, but not V. I do now, thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By definition, potential is a measure of how much work is necessary to bring a test charge, $q$ from infinity to a particular point. In the case of bringing a test charge, $q$ to somewhere in the region $0\leq r\leq a$, we first have to bring the particle through a field between $r>b$, and then through a field, $0\leq r\leq a$. That is, we exert a force equal and opposite the force exerted along the field, $-E$, the entire way to our desired point. However, because $E$ changes infinitesimally, we compute this via an integral (or rather a series of integrals).

From $r=\infty\to b$, we have, $$V=-\int_\infty^b\frac{1}{4\pi\epsilon_0}\frac{q}{r^2} \mathrm d r=\frac{q}{4\pi\epsilon_0}\frac{1}{r}\bigg\rvert_\infty^b=\frac{q}{4\pi\epsilon_0}\frac{1}{b}.$$

In the region, $a\leq r\leq b$, the electric field is $0$, and so the work done is also zero. Finally, in the region, $0\leq r\leq a$, we have (to bring a test charge from $a$, the bound to somewhere within the region, $r$), such that, $$V=-\int_a^r\frac{q}{4\pi\epsilon_0}\frac{1}{r^2}\mathrm d r=\frac{q}{4\pi\epsilon_0}\frac{1}{r}\bigg\rvert_a^r=\frac{q}{4\pi\epsilon_0}\left(\frac{1}{r}-\frac{1}{a}\right).$$ Summing the total work done then, we have, $$V(r)=\frac{q}{4\pi\epsilon_0}\left(\frac{1}{r}-\frac{1}{a}+\frac{1}{b}\right).$$ This is equivalent to the potential at a point $r$ in the region, $0\leq r\leq a$.

On a more procedural note, the general idea is, $$V=-\int_\infty^rE\,\mathrm d r,$$ where we might have to break up the integral into different bits as the e-field varies over space.

**Edit to address comment:**

I'll clarify what I meant by, test charge, $q$.  If we place a test charge, $q$ at any point in an electric field, the force on $q$ is given by $qE$. In calculating work then, we would technically have to integrate the expression $-qE$, over our specified bounds, however, because $q$ (the test charge) is a constant, we can just ignore it. The expression that I arrived at in my solution ignores the test charge, and the $q$ in the solution refers only to the charge generating the field. If we multiply the final $V(r)$ by test charge, $q$ we end up with potential experienced by that test charge, but the general potential is just $V(r)$. Hope that clears up some stuff.

Comment: If the charge $q$ is the test charge, shouldn't you specify that the $q$ in the integral is the charge that is *generating* the field? Or do we want to integrate considering the field produced by the moving charge? Thanks a lot  for the answer, it was really useful and I understand it now :)

Comment: No problem. I've edited my answer to clarify what I meant by test charge, $q$.

Answer (score 1):

Finding the expression $E(r)$ is a straightforward application of Gauss' Law.

To find the electric potential, first consider the relationship:$$\vec E (\vec r)= - \nabla V(\vec r)$$
This can be reduced to a single dimension, since by spherical symmetry we know nothing depends on $\theta$ or $\phi$. Taking the gradient operator $\nabla$ in spherical coordinates, and noting that all partial derivatives by $\theta$ and $\phi$ are zero, we obtain:
$$\vec E(\vec r) = - \hat r \frac{\partial V}{\partial r}$$
Since $\vec E$ is always pointing in the same direction, we may express it as a scalar function (its magnitude) of $r$ and say
$$E(r) = - \frac{\partial V(r)}{\partial r}$$
from which it is simple to integrate $E(r)$ in order to find $V(r)$. The constant of integration is arbitrary, as only *differences* in potential matter. Though it is commonplace to choose $V(r \rightarrow \infty) = 0$, as has been done in this case.